# 802.11G wireless router and low speed

Tags: router, performance, wireless-router

I need help figuring out why my devices do not go past 15Mbps download speed on my 802.11g network. (using https://fast.com/)

When plugged in to the LAN port, I get up to 50Mbps(max). The speed of 802.11g should be up to 54 Mbps. I read that when the wireless signal between two connected Wi-Fi devices is not strong, the Wi-Fi protocol reduces its maximum transmission speed to a lower number to maintain the connection.

However I tested being right next to the router and my connection never exceeds 15Mbps.

I have a Linksys WRT120N Cisco router. I tried configuring it for mode G only, adjusting beacon interval from default 100 higher, but no change.Any ideas as to what else I should be doing? It stays at that speed with a single or few devices connected to the router.

2nd related question: If it's an older router, and I purchase another router what do I need to look for to get speed up to 50Mbps?

Thanks for your help!
Reference https://www.linksys.com/no/support-article/?articleNum=135283 https://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/WRT120N_V10_UG_NC-WEB,0.pdf

Comment: Try one or two  of your devices on a different router to see if the issue is your device or the router. Likely the router. I have not seen a G router in about a decade or so, so it will be an  old device, likely in need of replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15Mbps was pretty typical for 802.11g in real-world conditions. Even if you have high signal strength by having your client close to your AP (wireless router), you probably can't control the noise on the channel (the 2.4GHz band is very crowded with Wi-Fi and non-Wi-Fi devices), and you probably can't control the traffic from neighboring networks on the same channel (or an overlapping channel).

802.11g hasn't been state of the art since 2003, and was officially obsoleted in 2007. You should buy a new AP that supports at least AC1200 with gigabit Ethernet ports. AC1200 is the Wi-Fi speed class that most modern Wi-Fi client devices support, and it's a little too early to buy into 802.11ax (AX, Wi-Fi 6) right now. If you have any wireless client devices that only support 802.11g, you should consider upgrading them to AC1200 as well. If it's a laptop, you could disable (completely power off; perhaps remove) its internal Wi-Fi adapter and use an external USB Wi-Fi dongle.

802.11g's maximum 54Mbps signaling rate only applies when your signal strength is good and your noise (interference) is low. Also, in those good conditions, *when a packet is being transmitted*, the bits are transmitted at 54Mbps, but there are mandatory gaps between packets and other sources of protocol overhead, so your devices are not constantly pumping out bits at 54Mbps; the overhead lowers your effective throughput. It's like having a 80km/h speed limit on a city street; you may get up to 80km/h sometimes, but other times you'll be stopped at an intersection, or have to yield to other slower traffic, so you're never going to make an 80km journey in 1 hour or less on that city street even though the speed limit seemed to suggest you could.

Standard 802.11g can hit just a hair above 20Mbps of throughput in ideal conditions (high signal-to-noise ratio, no other traffic on the channel). Some vendors did semi-proprietary "frame bursting" on 802.11g that brought that up to 30Mbps, but no one ever saw more than that on 802.11g.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!